# Mean calculation between dataframes in list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, concatenation, mean

I have a list of dataframes that all have the same format (same number of rows, same number of columns and columns have the same name).

I would like to create a new dataframe which has the same amount of column as any of the dataframes of the list like shown under.

List:

1. [[1]]

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 0.1 | 0.4 | 4 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 5 |

2. [[2]]

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 4 |
| 0.1 | 0.4 | 5 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 6 |

3. [[3]]

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 5 |
| 0.1 | 0.4 | 6 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 7 |

The result I would like is a dataframe like

Desired Output with mean calculation (only column Z):

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 4 |
| 0.1 | 0.4 | 5 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 6 |

Desired Output with sd calculation (only column Z):

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.3 | 1 |
| 0.1 | 0.4 | 1 |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 1 |

Columns X and Y are the same in the output as in all dataframes and column Z is a mean or standard deviation.

4, 5 and 6 beeing means from the three dataframes.
1 being the standard deviation of (3,4,5) or (4,5,6) or (5,6,7)
Unlike in this example I can have a lot of dataframes in my list (like 100).

If anyone has a clue

Answer (score 3):

Place the datasets in a `list` and get the elemenwise sum (`+`) and divide by the length of the `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, lst1)/length(lst1)
```

-output

```
    X   Y Z
1 0.1 0.3 4
2 0.1 0.4 5
3 0.2 0.4 6
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `array` and then use `rowMeans` by looping over the `MARGIN`

```
apply(array(unlist(lst1), c(dim(lst1[[1]]), length(lst1))),
    2, rowMeans)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.1  0.3    4
[2,]  0.1  0.4    5
[3,]  0.2  0.4    6
```

---

Or another option is to bind the datasets with `bind_rows`, create a sequence (`rowid` from `data.table`), grouped by the sequence and get the `mean` of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(lst1, .id = 'id') %>%
   group_by(id = rowid(id)) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-id)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      X     Y     Z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.1   0.3     4
2   0.1   0.4     5
3   0.2   0.4     6
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(structure(list(X = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2), Y = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.4
), Z = 3:5), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    X = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2), Y = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.4), Z = 4:6), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(X = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2), Y = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.4
), Z = 5:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it works. in your second option, is there a way to only get the mean of the third column. I might also do SD calculations so I would like to keep the first two columns the same and only apply rowMeans or rowSDs on the third one.

In your third option, do I nee to replace id with something, because I get an error:
Error in select(., -id) : unused argument (-id)

Comment: @Jean-AlexandrePatteet can you please update your post with expected output

Comment: I just did, I hope it's more clear

Comment: @Jean-AlexandrePatteet your expected output numbers for `sd` seems to be wrong because `sd(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1))#
[1] 0`, if you want elementwise, then do the `apply(array(unlist(lst1), c(dim(lst1[[1]]), length(lst1))),
     1:2, sd)`

Comment: I do not want the sd of c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),  I am only interested in the sd of the column Z. Values in columns X and Y are the same in all my dataframes (they are for each row a couple of parameters) and the cell in Z is the result of a function computed with those parameters (row by row). I have edited the question again to make it clearer.